# No internet access on Arch Linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux

Today I installed Arch Linux on my laptop. Everything seems to work okay, except Internet access.

I have tons of tutorials, nothing works. When I type `ping google.com` it returns

> `unknown host google.com.`

My whole `rc.conf` file:

```
INTERFACE=eth0
```

Comment: we might need some more information, like your dns settings, is your networkcard installed and enabled, your eth0 settings, can you reach other devices on your network. etc

Comment: 1. How to install and enable ntework card. 2. Where to find eth0 setting and stuff. 3. I am compleate newwbie to arch, used to fedora, dont know anything about this ://

Comment: Its suicide... Want to get arch working !

Comment: This is simply not enough information, and because this is not a forum site, we can't walk you through all the steps you don't know how to do. Try more googling, or a forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the Beginners Guide on How to establish a network connection in the arch wiki
[Arch Wiki Beginners Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_Guide#Establish_an_internet_connection).

Arch uses systemd, while initscripts as rc.conf are deprecated and no longer used.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, rc.conf is deprecated. I think your issue is around incorrectly setting up eth0 as your network interface. You probably want to check out this thread in addition to the Beginners Guide mentioned.

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=156283

Specifically check how your interface is mapped when you run 'ip link'. It may not be eth0!